Can I force PowerQuery to clear the Data Model before refreshing?
I'm trying to develop an audit tool to track changes in our product library (bureaucracy prevents a better option) but when I refresh my live DB query and compare it to the previous copy, I notice the case had changed on some values but when I manually queried the data in SSMS, the case had not changed. Example:
Product name in "live" PQ:     TEST PRODUCT A
Product name in archived copy: test product a
Product name in live SSMS:     test product a
This should result in no rows in the comparison but for this product, I get 1 row as the case is different between the live and archived versions but in reality, it's exactly the same!
I've even tried deleting all the values in the table in the sheet it loads to and refreshing the query but it seems it just brings the data model in.
From what I can tell, Excel simply checks to see if the number of rows has changed. If it hasn't, the data isn't updated. Am I missing something really basic, here?
Thanks in advance

You may want to consider adding a Text.Upper(your values) or Text.Lower in Power Query or the equivalent in SQl
This way you standardize the comparison by forcing it. One of them takes the text at face value and the other applies an Upper transformation to it.
Apply it to both columns used to compare and it will only display the differences in spelling or new values
